# Recursively Extract all 7z

Tags: find, archive, 7zip

I have many 7z archives nested in many subfolders, and want to extract all these archives into the folders in which they reside, then delete the original archives.

I have found how to do this, while extracting to the root directory.

```
while [ "`find . -type f -name '*.7z' | wc -l`" -gt 0 ]; do find -type f -name "*.7z" -exec 7za x -- '{}' \; -exec rm -- '{}' \;; done
```

However all archives are unpacked to the directory in which I carried out the command -- I want to extract said archives to their original locations preserving the original structure, but am not sure how to change it to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `-execdir` instead of `-exec`;

```
find . -type f -name "*.7z" -execdir 7za x {} \; -exec rm -- {} \;
```

`-execdir` runs in the directory containing the file. From [`man find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/find.1.html):

```
-execdir command {} +
      Like   -exec,   but  the  specified  command  is  run  from  the
      subdirectory containing the matched file, which is not  normally
      the  directory  in  which  you  started  find.
```

Other comments:

Use `-quit` in the `while` check's `find`, so that `find` doesn't continue searching after a match was found (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13880/70524):

```
while [ -n "$(find . -type f -name '*.7z' -print -quit)" ]
do 
    find . -type f -name "*.7z" -execdir 7za x {} \; -exec rm -- {} \;
done
```

Comment: @Arronical that would be an excellent reaction on [unix.se], where one can't assume GNU find.

Comment: Does the "rm" command get run even if the 7za extraction fails? (e.g., disk space)?    Ideally, it should be run only if 7za is successful (error code 0).

Comment: @whiskeychief Yes, subsequent actions won't be run if the 7za command has a non-zero exit status - that's the case with the `{} ;` form of `-exec` used here. If we were using `{} +`, on the other hand, then the exit status would essentially be ignored.